# IIF Statements with blank or alpha characters in MS Visual Basic

Tags: reporting-services

I have a field CODE_USER_2 that can be equal to 1.75, 2, 2.62, 3.75, 5.25, 6, OT(w/2 spaces, or *_*_(4 spaces).  If it is 1.75, 2, 2.62, 3.75, 5.25, 6 I would like corresponding weights to result (THIS PART WORKS).

If the field is **__ or OT**, I would like the equation to result with 0. I currently get  #error with the following formula.

=IIf(Fields!CODE_USER_2_IM.Value= "   " OR "OT  " ,0,Switch(Fields!CODE_USER_2_IM.Value=1.75,.629,Fields!CODE_USER_2_IM.Value=2,.67,Fields!CODE_USER_2_IM.Value=2.62,1.089,Fields!CODE_USER_2_IM.Value=3.75,1.767,Fields!CODE_USER_2_IM.Value=5.25,3.224,Fields!CODE_USER_2_IM.Value=6,3.895))

Please let me know if you have ideas!

Comment: What language is this code in? If I had to guess, it's from an Excel spreadsheet? Please can you retag your question appropriately.

Comment: For Microsoft Visual Studio (SSRS).  Thank you for pointing that out.  I wish it was for excel, but the formulas in Visual Studio are different/new to me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to repeat "Fields!CODE_USER_2_IM.Value = " after the OR.

Or try this - less wordy but more obscure :

=IIf( ( " |OT |" ).Contains(Fields!CODE_USER_2_IM.Value + "|"

,0,Switch(Fields!CODE_USER_2_IM.Value=1.75,.629,Fields!CODE_USER_2_IM.Value=2,.67,Fields!CODE_USER_2_IM.Value=2.62,1.089,Fields!CODE_USER_2_IM.Value=3.75,1.767,Fields!CODE_USER_2_IM.Value=5.25,3.224,Fields!CODE_USER_2_IM.Value=6,3.895

, True , 0))

Always close out a Switch with:

, True , [default value] )

Also beware that matching in SSRS expressions is exact e.g. 2 spaces not =  4 spaces.